# Difficulty using a CHAR in Dynamic SQL

Tags: dynamic-sql

I'm trying to pass in **@accountType**, a char value to a stored procedure that uses dynamic SQL. It is declared as `char(4)` in the procedure. The current error is `Incorrect syntax near 'D'` if I try to change it I get `invalid column: D`.

I cannot figure out how dynamic SQL wants me to indicate that the variable is a char. I've tried it many ways, here is the most recent:

```
set @q = 'Update ' + @statementTable +
     ' SET Account = '+ @padding + @accountNumber +
     ' WHERE ClosingDate BETWEEN CAST('''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@proc_dateStart)+''' AS DATE) AND CAST('''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@proc_dateEnd)+''' AS DATE)' +
     ' AND AccountType =' + ''''+ @accountType +''''
```

The value is coming from my C# code exactly like this: `D`

No single quotes or anything around the letter. Any ideas? I'm more than a bit stuck with this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, you need to have the parameters actually within the string statement, then when you execute sp_executesql, you then pass what each of those parameters are.

```
DECLARE @q VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @statementTable VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @padding VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @accountNumber CHAR(4)
DECLARE @proc_dateStart VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @proc_dateEnd VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @accountType VARCHAR(50)

SET @q = 'Update @statementTable
SET Account = ''@accountNumber''
WHERE ClosingDate BETWEEN CAST(''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@proc_dateStart)+'' AS DATE) AND CAST(''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@proc_dateEnd)+'' AS DATE)
AND AccountType = ''@accountType'''

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@statementTable VARCHAR(50),@accountNumber CHAR(4),@proc_dateStart VARCHAR(50), @proc_dateEnd VARCHAR(50),@accountType VARCHAR(50)', 
    @statementTable,@accountNumber,@proc_dateStart,@proc_dateEnd,@accountType;
```